# Powershell - Display matching custom object properties in single table

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with the output of my script displaying information in the way that I would like it to.  I would like to view the matching properties (objects are generated in a foreach loop, so they will always have the exact same properties) of each generated custom object under one table, instead of creating a new table for each object like the script below currently does.  Is this possible with the way this script creates the object?  If so, how would it be done?

```
function Get-Uptime
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
               Position=0)]
    [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
)

Begin {}
Process {
   foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
       $ComputerObject = [Ordered]@{"Computer Name" = $computer
                                    "Start Time" = $null
                                    "Uptime (Days)" = $null
                                    "Status" = $null
                                    "May Need Patched?" = $null}
       $IsOnline = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Quiet
       if ($IsOnline = $true) {
           Try { 
           #Collect information about each computer
           $WMIObject = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
           #Convert LastBootUpTime to readable date/time
           $ComputerObject.'Start Time' = $WMIObject.ConvertToDateTime($WMIObject.LastBootUpTime)
           #Convert LocalDateTime to readable date/time
           $ComputerObject.Uptime = $WMIObject.ConvertToDateTime($WMIObject.LocalDateTime)
           #Collect the number of days that have elapsed between
           $TimeElapsed = New-TimeSpan -Start $ConvertedBootUpTime -End $ConvertedLocalTime
           $ComputerObject.'Uptime (Days)' = [Math]::Round($TimeElapsed.TotalDays,1) 
           $ComputerObject.'May Need Patched?' = If ($ComputerObject.'Uptime (Days)' -ge "30"){$True} Else{$False}
           $ComputerObject.Status = "Online"
           }
           Catch {
           Write-Error "Unable to gather uptime for $Computer"
           $ComputerObject.Status = "Error"
           }
       }
       else {
           Write-Error "Computer $Computer is either non-existant or offline"
           $ComputerObject.Status = "Offline"
       }
       [PSCustomObject]$ComputerObject | ft
       }
}
End {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're calling Format-Table on each object as you're displaying them. Remove that and you're set.